# How can I solve the entity framework core 'code-first' many-to-many relations cascade deletion problem?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have three entity classes in my database model which have relations many-to-many.

**The first is `Item.cs`**

```
public class Item 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemsFeatures> ItemsFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

**The second is `Feature.cs`**

```
public class Feature
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ItemsFeatures> ItemsFeatures { get; set; }
}
```

**The third and last is `ItemsFeatures.cs`**

```
public class ItemsFeatures
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int FetureId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public Item Item { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeatureId")]
    public Feature Feature { get; set; }
}
```

According to my scenario

1-) If I delete an item, all related records with that item must be deleted from ItemsFeatures table.

2-) If I delete a feature, all related records with that feature must be deleted from ItemsFeatures table.

Entity Framework Core creates the `CreateTable` function in migration class as I want.

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "ItemsFeatures",
            columns: table => new
            {
                ItemId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                FeatureId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_ItemsFeatures", x => new { x.ItemId, x.FeatureId });
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_ItemsFeatures_Features_FeatureId",
                    column: x => x.FeatureId,
                    principalTable: "Features",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_ItemsFeatures_Items_ItemId",
                    column: x => x.ItemId,
                    principalTable: "Items",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });
```

But when I run `dotnet-ef database update` command, an error occurrs like below;

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ItemsFeatures_Items_ItemId' on table 'ItemsFeatures' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. 
Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

I know if I set `ON DELETE NO ACTION`, the problem will fix but I don't want `ON DELETE NO ACTION`. I want `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Why I can't set as I want?

Comment: you can use .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction) instead of cascade

Comment: "I have three entity classes in my database model" These 3 classes (as shown here) do not form cycles or multiple cascade paths. There must be something else (for instance common relationship from `Item` and `Feature` like `public User CreatedBy { get; set; }` or similar) which is causing the cycle. You need to find it and break the multiple cascade paths by turning at least one of the cascade delete off (it doesn't need to be from these two) - there is no other way since the error originates from SqlServer database limitation. You can find many similar posts here ...

Comment: ... if you search for "cycles or multiple cascade paths".

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev. As you said the `Item` entity had a `[Required]` foreign key `ItemTypeId` from another entity called by `ItemType`. I removed the `[Required]` attribute of `ItemTypeId` and it fixed.